# Constructing a subset of an uncountable set which is neither countable nor co-countable

Tags: set-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an uncountable set. Without assuming the axiom of choice, does there exist a subset $S\subset \Omega$ such that neither $S$ nor $\Omega\setminus S$ is countable?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Impossible. It is consistent with ZF (i.e. Zermelo-Frankel set theory *without* axiom of choice) that there is an infinite set $X$ such that if $A$ and $B$ divides $X$ (i.e. $A\cap B = \varnothing$ and $A\cup B = X$) then either $A$ or $B$ must be finite. Such set is called *amorphous set*. Of course, such set does not exist when assuming choice.

If $X$ is amorphous and $S\subset X$, then one of $S$ or $X-S$ should be finite, so it is impossible that both $S$ and $X-S$ are uncountable. Moreover, countable set should not be amorphous, since we can divide countable sets into two countable sets  (e.g. divide  $\Bbb{N}$ into odds and evens) so any amourphos set is uncountable. (In fact, every amorphous set can not contain countably infinite subsets.)

Comment: If you allow me, I would suggest you to include in your answer that an amorphous set can NOT be countable.

Comment: @Ramiro Thanks for your comment. I add it.

Comment: I see: even the existence of a countable subset of an uncountable set relies on the axiom of choice.

Comment: @pre-kidney: You can actually construct $\aleph_1$-amorphous set, where every subset is countable or co-countable. These sets can carry quite a lot more structure than just amorphous sets.