# Using the axiom of choice to construct uncountable non-cocountable subsets of a set

Tags: set-theory

This question is a natural follow up to [Constructing a subset of an uncountable set which is neither countable nor co-countable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1459041/constructing-a-subset-of-an-uncountable-set-which-is-neither-countable-nor-co-co).

Let $\Omega$ be an uncountable set. Using the axiom of choice, how can we construct a subset $S\subset \Omega$ which is neither countable nor co-countable?

Comment: Also [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/17432/uncountable-subset-with-uncountable-complement-without-the-axiom-of-choice), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853113/), and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/384619/). To both of your questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $f: \mathcal{P}(\Omega)-\emptyset \to \Omega$ is a choice function, construct two sequences $(a_\xi)$, $(b_\xi)$ by transfinite recursion with

$a_\xi=f(\Omega-(\{a_\eta:\eta < \xi\} \cup \{b_\eta:\eta < \xi\}))$
and $b_\xi=f(\Omega-(\{a_\eta:\eta \leq \xi\} \cup \{b_\eta:\eta < \xi\}))$.

The process does not stop at any countable ordinal by uncountability of $\Omega$.

Answer (score 1):

well-order your set $\Omega$, and pick all those points whose index is a limit ordinal. You can easily show that if $\alpha$ is an uncountable ordinal, then the set of limit ordinals is neither countable, nor co-countable.

This allows you even slightly better control on the cardinality of the set you create (or the cardinality of its complement).